# skew normal distribution in multivariate case using matlab

Tags: r, matlab, random, distribution, skew

how can we generate random numbers using skew normal distribution in multivariate case?

Comment: I added some new tags to your question to be more specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `rsn` function from the `sn` package in R (as I think from another question that R will work for you also):

```
rsn(n=100, location=1.256269, scale=1.605681, shape=5)
```

Will generate 100 (`n`) random numbers from a skew-normal distribution with the required location, scale and shape. Use higher sample size for plotting, e.g.:

```
hist(rsn(n=10000, location=1.256269, scale=1.605681, shape=5))
```

[image]

Comment: I have just noticed that you need random numbers from a multivariate skew-normal distribution. Use `rmsn()` function (also from the *sn* library) with appropriate parameters instead of the suggested `rsn()` function.